# $(A^H . A).v = \lambda.v \Rightarrow \lambda\in \Bbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{tr}(A^H.A)\ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$How to prove that for a $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$ such that 
$(1)$ $(A^\dag.A).v=\lambda.v$, $\bar{\lambda}=\lambda\Leftrightarrow \lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ and $(2)$ $\operatorname{tr}(A^\dag.A)\ge 0$?

For $(2)$, I put that as $(A^\dag.A)_{ii}=A^\dag_{ij}.A_{ji}=\bar{A}_{ji}.A_{ji} = \lVert A_{ji}\rVert^2_2\ge 0$ it is proved that $\operatorname{tr}(A^\dag.A)=\sum_i(A^\dag.A)_{ii}\ge 0$.

For $(1)$, how can I prove that $R^\dag.v=\bar{\lambda}.v$, such that, $\bar{\lambda}.v=R^\dag.v=(A^\dag.A)^\dag.v=A^\dag.A.v=R.v=\lambda.v\Rightarrow \bar{\lambda}=\lambda\Rightarrow\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: $A^HA$ is Hermitian and positive semidefinite. What can be said about the eigenvalues of such a matrix?

Comment: Regarding your second statement: note that $\bar A_{ji} \cdot A_{ji} = |A_{ji}|^2$ is necessarily non-negative.  So, you already have enough to answer part (2).

Answer (score 1):

We Know that $A^HA$ is Hermitian positive, indeed :
$$∀x∈\mathbb R^n,\ <A^HAx,x>=<Ax,Ax>=\Vert Ax\Vert^2⩾0$$
For the fact that this matrix is hermitian is clear to show, therefore we have proved that all the eigenvalues of $A^HA$ are positives, so we have :
$$Tr(A^HA)=\sum_{\lambda∈Sp(A^HA)}\lambda ⩾0$$